# Implementing Latin Hypercube sampling from skewed distributions in Java

Tags: java, sampling, skew, latin, hypercube

I have 5 parameters represented by skewed discrete distributions. I want to do Latin Hypercube sampling from these distributions. Most of the examples I could find on the internet use LHS from normal or uniform distributions and they are in Python.

Are there any algorithm /sample program/library for LH sampling from skewed distributions that i can use in Java?

In Python, I have tried pearson3 library.